# Xcode: Deleting project from project navigator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I imported another project into my own project, but instead of putting it inside my own project is is on same level as my project. That means i can't delete it from the project navigator, or at least i do not know how to do it ?

Anyone with same problem and maybe a solution ?

Comment: Normally when i look in my project manager then there is my project, when i expand it all the project files will show.. I wanted to put the other project into my project, but instead i put it in the project manager... So now i have 2 projects i can expand, instead of one.

Comment: That's only a guess. Try to locate your project file, option-click -> Show Package Content. Do the same for project.xcworkspace file. Open contents.xcworkspacedata file with a text editor, there might be two FileRef entries, remove the one you don't want to have, save and reopen the project, perform clean.  I believe xcuserdata folders might be also removed to avoid interface state issues. I would try it myself and suggest as solution if worked, but Xcode 4.2 doesn't allow to reproduce that issue (remember it from a past however). Let us know if it worked.

Comment: cool, added as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate your project file, option-click -> Show Package Content. Do the same for project.xcworkspace file. Open contents.xcworkspacedata file with a text editor, there might be two FileRef entries, remove the one you don't want to have, save and reopen the project, perform clean. I believe xcuserdata folders might be also removed to avoid interface state issues.